# how to create command to delete a role in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem, I have no idea how to delete a role through discord.js

having no idea I don't have any code

I only have code to get the name of the role that the user wants to delete, and verify if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Role` class has a method called `delete()` that deletes a role type. You can find the Discord.js documentation on this [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=delete). The following code is taken from there, and assuming you have defined the role, you can use the following code to remove it:

```js
role.delete('The role needed to go')
  .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted role ${deleted.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

If you need to retrieve the role given it's name, you can use this:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    const guild = client.guilds.get("GUILDID"); //Put in GuildID
    const role = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ROLENAME"); //Put your role name in

    //Now delete the role...
})
```

Of course, you don't need to run this on ready, and can get the guild based off a message:

```
let guild = message.guild;
const role = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ROLENAME"); //Put your role name in

//Delete role
```

Comment: me sale este error 
(node:28048) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

{ DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

    at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/37a20212-2fd5-4d84-8209-0cb6ac43bf5d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)

    at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/37a20212-2fd5-4d84-8209-0cb6ac43bf5d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)

Comment: I've updated the deprecation warning, as for the error, your bot can only remove a role if it has higher roles than the role to be deleted, so you need to grant the bot higher permissions